# How do I create a .bat file that will make iterative file names?

Tags: batch-file, windows-10

I'm new to writing batch files so I'm still a trying to work things out. Basically, I want to create a `.bat` file that will create a list of directories with a incremented number on the end. For my example I will get files with the names "Week1", "Week2", "Week3" ... "Week52". My code is as follows:

`set "prefix=Week"
for /l %%x in (1, 1, 52) do (
    set /a num=%%x
    set direc=%prefix%%num%
    mkdir %direc% 
)`

I think the trouble comes on the line where I concatenate the string and the numbers but I'm not 100% sure. Any pointers/corrections? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are you getting instead of "Week1", "Week2" etc.?

Comment: Don't bother setting `%num%` at all; just use `%%x` as a suffix.

Comment: ChrisF - I just got an error for each command and one folder named "Week".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need [delayed Expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082):

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "prefix=Week"
for /l %%x in (1, 1, 52) do (
  set /a num=%%x
  set direc=%prefix%!num!
  mkdir !direc! 
)
```

but why creating variables?

```
set "prefix=Week"
for /l %%x in (1, 1, 52) do mkdir %prefix%%%x
```

Comment: First code with delayedexpansion. Should be :   `set direc=%prefix%!num!
  mkdir !direc! 
)`

Comment: @SachaDee yes, of Course, that's the Point. Got lost during editing the second Code snipped :(  Corrected.